# Does lemon juice slow the oxidation of guacamole?

Tags: chemistry, cooking

It is common belief that adding citrus juice (or in some claims, any acid, including ascorbic acid/vitamin C, vinegar, tomatoes, etc) to guacamole will reduce browning.  Examples of the claim:

- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/9358/6498)

  > You can stop this reaction dead in it's tracks by introducing an acid.
- [Askville](http://askville.amazon.com/homemade-guacamole-turning-brown/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=6017381)

  > The acid you use can range from tomatoes to vinegars to lemons/limes. Regardless of your preference, it must be added immediately to stave off oxyidzation; the reason guac browns.
- [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_4608191_prevent-guacamole-turning-brown.html)

  > Add something acidic!

However, there are also claims to the contrary, that adding acid to guacamole has no effect, or can even have a negative effect:

- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/24603/6498)

  > It's a myth, as is adding something acidic.
- [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/2012/01/the-food-lab-the-best-guacamole-avocados-science-browning-ripening.html)

  > What about acid? Many books claim that lime or lemon juice will prevent avocados from browning. That's not what my tests said. In fact, depending on how much I added, some batches of guacamole actually browned faster in the presence of citrus juice—significantly so. By the time I added enough acid to slow the browning down to a reasonable degree, the guacamole was inedibly sour.

Is it true that adding something acidic to guacamole will prevent an enzyme reaction, that causes oxidization, and thus browning?

Comment: The same is claimed for bananas!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*I love this question, because, until now, I never doubted lemon juice worked.
I love this answer, because it surprised me even more than the question.*

**Yes... and No! Lemon juice may make things better or worse. It depends on the avocado! Ascorbic acid works though.**

- R. P. Bates, [THE RETARDATION OF ENZYMATIC BROWNING IN AVOCADO 
  PUREE AND GUACAMOLE](http://www.avocadosource.com/Journals/FSHSP/FSHSP_VOL_81_PG_230-235_1968.pdf), Proc. Fla. State Hort. Soc. 81:230-235. 1968.

In this study,  the author looked at different mechanisms to reduce the browning of both plain avocado (in puree form), or a standardised batch of guacamole (which itself, contained lemon juice).

Bates tried to use a photometer to precisely measure the browning, and describes the difficulties found.

Bates started with a "Booth 8" avocado, from Florida.

> Lemon juice at 2 and 4% was of no value and actually speeded up browning during the 
>   first 4 hours [...], although after 8 hours the control sample read as low [...].

Then, later in the season, replaced it with a "Lula" avocado, also from Florida.

> Lula browned much less rapidly. Also, samples acidified with lemon juice 
>   browned less rapidly than the control [...]. **It is not too surprising that a different 
>   browning response was observed since in morphology and flavor these two varieties 
>   are quite different.**

The author goes on to recommend some other, more successful preservatives based on other experiments described in the paper - including sodium bisulfite and/or **ascorbic acid**. There are descriptions of some combinations, including lemon juice, where the extra acidity may help improve the effect of the sodium bisulfite.